# How can I extract a string between <strong> tags usings C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have a string such as below:

```
"Unneeded text <strong>Needed Text</strong> More unneeded text"
```

How can I extract only the "**Needed Text**"? I'm guessing Regex is likely the simplest way but Regex still looks like hieroglyphics to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685570/regex-to-extract-text-between-a-html-tag (or more preferably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702835/use-regex-to-extract-text-between-html-tags) will take care of you.  These immediately popped up with a simple google search for "extract text between html tags".

Comment: [Don't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1895201)

Comment: Your answer is here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/regex-c-sharp-find-a-string-between-2-known-values

Comment: Are you trying to extract from an XML file ?

Comment: No. It is an HTML string stored in a SQL db that is used to help format a document. I'm extracting a portion of the string to use in a dropdownlist. The method will not be used a whole lot and server space is a bit of an issue.

Comment: @DGibbs - While normally true, this particular case is simple enough that it's reasonable to use them.

Comment: @Bobson How do you know that it's simple enough?  For the one single example that the OP gave it can work fine, but he just says that he has HTML text stored in a string.  How do you know that other values don't have much more complex HTML values that wouldn't be able to be properly parsed by even any regex, let alone the particular solutions in the answers below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<strong>(.*)</strong>");
  var v = regex.Match("Unneeded text <strong>Needed Text</strong> More unneeded text");
  string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Note that given the string `"Unneeded text <strong>Needed text</strong> Less useful <strong>More useful</strong>"`, it'll capture the `Less useful` too.  I suggest `(.*?)` instead.

Comment: To clarify, the "?" after .* will make it "lazy", meaning it'll stop as soon as it can match next.

Comment: I gave @Anna.P the check because she provided what I needed in a comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/regex-c-sharp-find-a-string-between-2-known-values and she also gave a solid answer pertaining to the Regex. Thanks, Anna.P

Answer (score 13):

You don't need regex for that.

You can use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "Unneeded text <strong>Needed Text</strong> More unneeded text";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<strong>") + "<strong>".Length, s.IndexOf("</strong>") - s.IndexOf("<strong>") - "<strong>".Length));
```

Output will be;

```
Needed Text
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/BPCAcR).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) or [AngleSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609053/AngleSharp)

Comment: I am familiar with HTML Agility Pack, but this method will only be used in one place in the application. I want to avoid beefing up the size too much.

Comment: Then use Substring as suggested by Soner, except I would replace the hard-coded 8 values with "<strong>".Length (obviously calculated once) to make the code more readable.

Comment: @JonEdwards Well, if the HTML code that you can have in this string can be most any valid HTML code then there really is no way around it.  Unless you can be *sure* that you're only dealing with a limited subset of HTML that doesn't contain any of the patterns that completely mess up regex-based solutions, then you won't be sure that you solution will work for all inputs.

Answer (score 5):

Use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and save yourself a headache. Something like this ought to do it:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("html...");

var innerText = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("strong").Select(x => x.InnerText).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, a simple `Split` would do it, e.g.

```
var innerText = text.Split('>')[1].Split('<')[0];
```

Comment: Somebody needs it for minimal scenario. This works for

    <li class="ui-state-default">ElementValue</li>

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple regular expression like:

```
(?<=<strong>).+?(?=<)
```