# Fastest way to get a part of a string (int) with a delimiter in C#

Tags: c#

I have a String like:

```
<1>something here just not relevant</1>
```

I need the fastest way to get the number 1.

My try:

`int signature = Convert.ToInt32(data.Split('>')[0].Remove(0, 1))`;

Comment: Are you guaranteed your string is formatted as XML?

Comment: [That's not XML](http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#NT-Name).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract a string between <strong> tags usings C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298353/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-strong-tags-usings-c)

Comment: @austinwernli Not quite; this OP wants the tag name, not what's between the tags.

Comment: ahh wow, read it wrong heh

Comment: Is the string always in that format, i.e. you want the number starting at the second character in the string and ending at the first occurrence of ">" in the string?

Comment: Does what you have work? If so, how does it perform now? In other words, are you seeing performance issues with it, and that's why you need the "fastest" or is this just Code Golf?

Comment: Have you already found that this is definitely a performance bottleneck in your program? If not, write the *simplest* code first, and then make sure you have concrete performance goals.

Comment: What is your performance budget (including memory usage). How large are the strings you need to support? What's the expected behavior if the tags contain non-digits?

Comment: [Whats the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](http://stackoverflow.com/a/199484/1115360ToInt32]).

Comment: int.Parse() converts only from strings. Convert.ToInt32() converts also from other data types. How they behave internally, don't know, I think someone will need to disassembly.

Comment: Please explain a bit more your scenario. Else everyone will try guessing. Is this a job interview question?

Comment: There really is no context as to the purpose of the question.  One could easily answer that signature = int.Parse(data.Substring(1,1))....

Comment: `int signature = 1;` also answers the question and is faster than anything else proposed so far.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: sorry for that, I think I was color blind not noticing the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun and surprisingly fast:

```
public static int GetSignature(string value)
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) // 12 should be more than enough for Int32
  {
    if (value[i] == '>')
    {
      break;
    }
    result = (result * 10) + (value[i] - '0');
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

Edit: My quick'n'dirty test setup

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Run(new Random());

    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private static void Run(Random rnd)
  {
    var counts = new[] { 10, 100000, 10000000 };

    foreach (var count in counts)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(count);
      Run(count, rnd);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }

  private static void Run(int count, Random rnd)
  {
    var values = GetValues(count, rnd);

    var funcs
      = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, int>>
      {
        {"OP", GetSignatureOP},
        {"Keith", GetSignatureKeith},
        {"Fun", GetSignatureFun},
      };

    foreach (var kvp in funcs)
    {
      TimeSpan elapsed;
      Test(values, kvp.Value, out elapsed);
      Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}: {1:G}", kvp.Key, elapsed);
    }
  }

  private static IList<string> GetValues(int count, Random rnd)
  {
    var result = new List<string>(count);

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
      result.Add(string.Format("<{0}>something here just not relevant</{0}>", rnd.Next(1, 10)));
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static int Test(IEnumerable<string> values, Func<string, int> func, out TimeSpan elapsed)
  {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var count = values.Aggregate(0, (current, value) => current ^ func(value));
    sw.Stop();

    elapsed = sw.Elapsed;

    return count;
  }


  private static int GetSignatureOP(string value)
  {
    return Convert.ToInt32(value.Split('>')[0].Remove(0, 1));
  }
  private static int GetSignatureKeith(string value)
  {
    return int.Parse(value.Substring(1, value.IndexOf('>') - 1));
  }
  private static int GetSignatureFun(string value)
  {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
      if (value[i] == '>')
      {
        break;
      }
      result = (result * 10) + (value[i] - '0');
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Results (on my machine):

```
10
OP   : 0:00:00:00,0007532
Keith: 0:00:00:00,0001523
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,0001307

100000
OP   : 0:00:00:00,0306495
Keith: 0:00:00:00,0116116
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,0018416

10000000
OP   : 0:00:00:02,7450986
Keith: 0:00:00:01,1598363
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,1855654
```

And with random values for `rnd.Next(1, int.MaxValue)`:

```
10
OP   : 0:00:00:00,0006975
Keith: 0:00:00:00,0001147
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,0001246

100000
OP   : 0:00:00:00,0409755
Keith: 0:00:00:00,0187789
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,0030894

10000000
OP   : 0:00:00:04,0060685
Keith: 0:00:00:01,9214684
Fun  : 0:00:00:00,3083399
```

Comment: It concerns me that this answer was accepted, even if technically answers the question

Comment: @MarkPeters - agreed. Although, going from what OP provided, the only information we have is that a) first character is irrelevant, b) the next n charactes represent a valid `Int32` value that c) ends at the character `'>'`. Which this does, too. And according to my tests, even a little bit faster than the other solutions. But I'd never use something like that in production code.

Comment: No problem with your answer.  It's the kind of answer I might write as an excuse to play (on a question without enough information). I'm concerned (by it being accepted) that it *will* end up in production code...

Comment: Some quick benchmarks for 10M iterations show about a 50X improvement for this one over the Regex variant.  Surprising?  Not that I would ever use this in production code without a good reason (like I needed to do it 10M times and it had proven to be the bottleneck)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - added test setup. -- Didn't bother with regex, because in my experience, that has always been slower for these very simple tasks.

Comment: I was impressed that I had to use a billion iterations to have it take any meaningful time on my machine (14 secs)

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "<1>something here just not relevant</1>";
result = int.Parse(str.Substring(1, str.IndexOf('>') - 1));
```

This should be faster than a Regex and will work as long as you can be sure the first character of the string is the opening angle bracket (and not whitespace or a previous tag). If you can't be sure of that, use a second `IndexOf`:

```
string str = "<1>something here just not relevant</1>";
var start = str.IndexOf('<')+1;
result = int.Parse(str.Substring(start, str.IndexOf('>') - start));
```

A Regex match would be more reliable and cleaner, but slightly slower:

```
string str = "<1>something here just not relevant</1>";
result = int.Parse(Regex.Match(str, "<(\d+)>").Captures[0]);
```